# How do I stub a Service from starting in an Espresso test?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I want to prevent a Service from starting so I can instead test it in isolation from my UI tests. The Service is triggered from a button press via a `startService` call in an Activity.

I've tried using the `Intents` class, but this does not appear to work with calls to `startService`:

`Intents.intending(IntentMatchers.hasComponent(MyService.class.getName())).respondWith(new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, null));`

It seems to only be relevant for Activity-based intents. I don't see anything else in the Espresso package for stubbing Service calls.

Comment: Any ideas in the meantime?

Comment: @Ewoks could always just wrap the call to start the service, then mock the wrapper.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit? Answering to yourself and accepting that answer is ok as well :)

Comment: @JasonRobinson did you ever find an answer?